# Get unique values from an array of objects based on two keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have the following array of objects:

```
[{x: "1", y: "2", test: "9.000", class: "low-latency"},
{x: "2", y: "3", test: "9.000", class: "low-latency"},
{x: "22", y: "22", test: "0.000", class: "low-latency"},
{x: "22", y: "22", test: "127.000", class: "high-latency"},
{x: "5", y: "6", test: "96.000", class: "high-latency"},
{x: "6", y: "7", test: "66.000", class: "low-latency"},
{x: "7", y: "8", test: "71.000", class: "high-latency"}]
```

This is a part of a react reducer so this gets updated every x number of seconds based on the data being returned from a socket.

What I need to do is make sure that when x and y have the same value - there should be just one of them. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can't this be done when the list is updated? That would be the most efficient way. Doing it after the fact would be *much* less desirable.

Comment: Also, I assume you would actually need to mutate the original array instead of creating a new, filtered array, since it seems to be shared. Is that right?

Comment: yup, thats correct...

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to use [_.uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy) and hash, eg.

```
_.uniqBy(arr, ({x,y}) => x+':'+y)
```